# Ajax отправка текста

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, chat

Что мне надо добавить в data: и сделать что бы он отправлял значение текстового поля message

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <iframe name='chatWindow' id='chatWindow'frameborder="no" height="935" width="1910" src='iframe.php'>Chat</iframe>

        <br>    <input type='text' id="text" name='message'>
            <input type='button' id="button" value="send">
            <script>
            $(document).ready (function () {
                $("#button").bind("click", function (){
                  $.ajax ({
                      url: "iframe.php",
                      type: "POST",
                      data: ({}),
                      dataType: "PHP"
                  });  
                });
            });
            </script>  
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вашего `input`'a стоит идентификатор `id='text'`, по нему и обращайтесь. Занесите его значение в переменную до `$.ajax`:

```
var msg = $('#text').val();
$.ajax ({
...
   data: msg,
...
```

Только в dataType пишется формат, в котором данные отправятся на сервер, в вашем случае `json`:

```
dataType: "json"
```

Comment: работает но почему что бы увидеть результат мне нужно обновлять страницу

Comment: Естественно, вам отдельно нужно писать код, который будет отображать отправленное сообщение. Советую вам детальней почитать документацию по jQuery http://jquery-docs.ru/ajax/jquery-ajax/#examples.